# Restrict the iphone app to install on only devices with Retina Display (iphone 4 / 4S )

Tags: ios, retina-display, uidevice

I am developing one iphone app. But I want to restrict my app to install only on device swith Retina Display. So my decision is to add UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key in plist file with front facing camera required so that my app will install on only devices with Retina Display.

So my question is does Apple reject my app as my app doesn't use front facing camera still I have added it to UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities ?
Also anybody has any other solution to restrict the to install on devices with Retina Display only?

Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Just out of interest, why do you want it to be retina display only? Is it that it uses tiny text that's too blurry to read on a 3GS display? Or is there some other reason.

Comment: I have some other reason. Its a reuirement of app.

Comment: Fair enough. Good luck with the app.

Comment: Can you tell me whether the apple will approve it or not?

Comment: My guess would be that it *might* get through, depending on how thorough  your reviewer is. Don't know for sure. Personally I wouldn't promise acceptance to a client.

Comment: You might be able to do something "fancy" within your code to restrict which devices can run it but I don't believe you have the ability to filter out such devices when you publish to the App Store.  In other words, if you publish an iPhone-only app, your app will be visible from within all iPhones.  That means pre-retina display devices could still download your app.  I doubt, however, Apple would accept such an app but I can't verify.

Comment: It might be worth noting that both the iPad 2 and the iPad mini are featuring front-facing cameras, so users may still be able to run your app on devices without retina display, unless you require "telephony" as well. However this in turn would lead to your app being unavailable on retina enabled iPad models too.

Comment: I'm looking for the same solution. Could you please share whether you were successful in submitting the app to AppStore with setting requirement for front camera? While it wasn't really needed in the app.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct requirement for installing only on Retina devices, but for iPhone/iPod Touch with retina you can set `front-facing-camera` requirement to `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` dictionary.
Front facing camera available only on iPhone 4 or later and iPod Touch 4th gen or later

PS: It's look like a hack if your application doesn't work with this camera, so I'm not sure about reviewing process.