# How to prevent iphone app from running on non-retina device?

Tags: iphone, ios, retina-display

I want my app to run on Retina devices only. How do i disable supporting non-Retina iPhone? Is that possible?

Comment: I guess you can create your app on iOS 5 sdk. But I don't recommend that since apple is very adamant about retina support.

Comment: Remove armv6 from Valid Architectures.

Comment: Refer http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/05/02/how-to-indicate-what-devices-are-supported-by-your-ios-app this link.

Comment: check this link-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10996105/restrict-the-iphone-app-to-install-on-only-devices-with-retina-display-iphone-4

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the screen size is same for iPhone 3G, 3Gs, 4, 4S; You won't be able to find out which one is retina display among them (AFAIK). But, from iPhone4 the device is having front facing camera, so, You can use that. You can have your App require **front-facing camera** (Just an example; there are other hardwares too, newly introduced from iPhone4) device capability.

These are specified in the plist file for the app using the `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` key.

A front-facing camera, that would limit it to those devices that have that, **eliminating the 3G and 3GS** (They are Non-retina displays).

For more details [`UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html)

Answer (score 1):

It may work! A hacky way!

You need two images temp.png and temp@2x.png

In your first view controller take a `UIButton` hidden from view, set background image of it --- temp.png, when your `viewDidLoad`called, that will set the background image for that button, after that, you can check with `if([buttonObject currentBackgroundImage] == [UIImage imageNamed:@"temp@2x.png"])` then its a `retina` support device, you may show some message to user, or do whatever you want to!

Comment: I am afraid that won't prevent the app running on devices with non-retina display.