# Retina only devices in iOS build

Tags: ios

Is there a way to exclude non-retina devices from the build and will is it allowed in the submission process? I am not targeting iPad or iPad mini. I think the 3GS users are minimal and the device cant process anything too advanced.

I do not want to have to include non retina artwork into the bundle.

Comment: That's a pretty poor reason to not support non-retina devices.  As far as your programming is concerned, all iPad touch inputs are in _points_, (ie both retina and non-retina devices use coordinates of 768x1024 points) not pixels.  To even get retina graphics to show up properly, [you have to set the content scale factor](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9763368/111307).

Comment: ?? I think you misunderstood what I am asking.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking how to prevent non-retina devices from even using your app.

Comment: I think you are over analysing. I know about points vs pixels, just asked if the app can be restricted to iPhones with retina only.

Comment: I think targeting is by iOS version only.  [I don't think you can cut out a device because it is non-retina](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16180968/111307)

Answer (score 2):

You should not exclude non retina device, since the iPad mini is non retine. Also there is no build option to exclude the non retina devices.

So non retina device will just run using retina images and use up more memory, wich could make them run out of memory. 
If you do manage to exclude the iPhone 3GS your app will still need to run on the iPad mini which is non retina even if you app is iPhone only it should run on any iPad.

Comment: Edited my question. I am not targeting iPad or iPad mini.

Comment: Makes no difference your app will still need to run on the iPad even if you are not targeting the iPad.

Comment: True, forgot about that one. With the weird @2x option for anything using pngs.

Answer (score 2):

In the past, you could use an approach like the one described in [this blog post](http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/05/02/how-to-indicate-what-devices-are-supported-by-your-ios-app).  After reading the post, refer to [this updated device capabilities matrix](http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/10/30/uirequireddevicecapabilities-and-device-compatibility-matrix).

Essentially, you pick a set of UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities keys that restricts the the set of supported devices to the ones that are retina display.

Unfortunately, as you can see from the matrix, the iPad mini invalidates this approach when it comes to Retina Display (it does not have Retina Display, but it is not lacking any other features that you could use to exclude it from the set of other Retina Display devices).

Edit: based on your edit, since you are not building for iPad/iPad mini, you can use the approach above and require front-facing-camera.

See also [this similar Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15779320/how-to-prevent-iphone-app-from-running-on-non-retina-device?lq=1).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to include non-retina artwork. Just use only non-@2x named images; that would lead to poor performance on non-retina devices, though, since they are also older and have slower hardware (iPad mini excluded). You can't exclude devices based on hardware (except maybe by setting minimum iOS version).

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible, unfortunately.

You can take a look at: [Information Property List Key Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html) where you can see the itens that you can configure what your app need to run.

Maybe you can take a look at the session: **UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities** to try to adjust it to only run on devices that have a certain combination of Capabilities, but like you can see on the page, it is not possible to configure it based on the device display.

-

One example of what you can do to support only devices with more powerfull hardware is to define that you need to use hardwares that only the latest devices have like: front-facing-camera. (iPad 2 has it, and isn't retina, is only an example of feature that you can take advantage).

Maybe inside your app you can check the scale, and take two different approachs.

```
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]
    && [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2.0) {
    [self runTheFeature];
} else {
    [self alertYourDeviceSucks];
}
```

Comment: [This isn't going to make it through the app submission process.](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html)

Comment: @bobobobo, Its is just an example, I am not expecting that he will show an alert, but run two differents approach.

Comment: I know but, for all intents and purposes this is a really bad idea.  The way it's engineered now is basically retina just "looks better" with 2x the pixels and you don't have to worry about it in your code.  The way you coded this, you now have to worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

You should not exclude non-retina devices, as the last answer says, but if you feel like you have to, then you can do this: 
1- in your app delegate check if the device has retina display before adding the main view controller to the UIWindow

```
if(IS_RETINA)
{
      [self initTheMainViewCotnroller];
}
else
{
      // show alert, warning or anything
      [self showErrorOrWarningMessage];
}
```

Note: IS_RETINA - is a macro

```
#define IS_RETINA ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(displayLinkWithTarget:selector:)] && ([UIScreen mainScreen].scale == 2.0))
```

Comment: Any negativity for the user is not good. I wanted to know if it is possible at build level or before even making it onto the device.